# Kubernetes MetalLB External IP not reachable from browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-networking, metallb

I have a nginx deployment with service type LoadBalancer.
I got a external IP which is accessible from master and worker node.
I am not able to access it from browser.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below steps to access it from the browser.

1. Deploy Nginx in your Kubernetes environment by executing the below YAML file.

   kubectl create -f {YAML file location}

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: nginx-deployment
 labels:
   app: nginx
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: nginx
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: nginx
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: nginx
       image: nginx:1.14.2
       ports:
       - containerPort: 80
```

[image]

2. Execute below nginx-service YAML to access it from the browser.

   kubectl create -f {YAML file location}

```
#Service
#nginx-svc-np.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.1.155
```

[image]

3. Now you can access Nginx from your browser.

   http://192.168.1.155/ **(Please use your external IP)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same. But I am running minikube. So, changing minikube driver helped me.